# Placing two characters touching

Tags: symbols

I would like to place the $+$ and $\equiv$ be nearly touching, almost as if they were one symbol. Is it possible to do this?

Currently, $+\equiv$ looks like this
[image]

What I would like is for these two symbols to be touching. the gap between them should not be present. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: $+\!\!\equiv$ How about that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by “touching”:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\plusequiv}{\mathrel{{+}{\equiv}}}

\newcommand{\plusequivt}{\mathrel{{+}\mkern-2mu{\equiv}}}

\newcommand{\plusequivx}{\mathrel{{+}\!{\equiv}}}

\begin{document}

$a\plusequiv b$

$a\plusequivt b$

$a\plusequivx b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Bracing the symbols prevents them to get their standard meaning of operation or relation; the surrounding `\mathrel` gives the combination the status of a relation.

Answer (score 5):

Is it one of these you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

$ +\color{red} \mkern-8mu\equiv$

$ +\color{red} \mkern-7mu\equiv$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good also this answer. I upvote also you.